# views slide show ajax load new content

Tags: 7, views

I have a site  displaying text in a slideshow format using  views slideshow. I was wondering if there is anyway to append  the slideshow with new  content created on the site maybe via  ajax. View out  refreshing the page

My current work around was to refresh the  view after the slideshow ends the  problem with this is that there is a visible break in the flow of the animation if the entire refreshes

Comment: Did you create separate content type for slideshow?

Comment: Yes there are two content types included in the slideshow